# Designing Inheritance with Abstract Return Types

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, inheritance, abstract-class

Here's a rough image of what I'm trying to achieve (it won't compile, so consider it pseudocode). Please note that even though the example is based on public key cryptographic schemes, the question is about design patterns, templates and inheritance.

```
class CryptoProvider
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    virtual T Encrypt ()
    {
        T data;

        return data;
    }
};

class Paillier : public CryptoProvider
{
public:
    typedef int Ciphertext;

    Ciphertext Encrypt ()
    {
        Ciphertext data;
        return data;
    }
};

class ElGamal : public CryptoProvider
{
public:
    struct Ciphertext
    {
    public:
        int c1;
        int c2;
    };

    Ciphertext Encrypt ()
    {
        Ciphertext data;
        return data;
    }
};
```

Basically, I want to provide some generic functionality in CryptoProvider, which can be overridden by the derived classes if required, because otherwise I would end up with lots of duplicate code. If `Encrypt` just needs to create a variable and call another function, then I don't want to write this code in every derived class, but, if a derived class needs to do some extra processing on the data, it should be able to overwrite the base method.

The biggest limitation that I've ran into is to somehow be able to override the Encrypt function by specifying completely different return types. Could somebody point me in the right direction on how to achieve this? Should I stick to traditional inheritance or should I try to go for compile-time / static polymorphism with [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)? I have no idea where to start.

I also want to impose the derived classes to implement certain methods, but I'm not sure how to achieve this, if the solution to the first issue requires that I discard standard inheritance (and I won't benefit from virtual methods)...

Comment: Are you aware that you can provide an implementation for a pure virtual function? This would force derived classes to implement it but would allow derived classes to use the same default implementation.

Comment: @hmjd Yes, of course, but I can't find any straight-forward way of overriding base class methods, if I want them to return different data types than the base declaration...

Comment: A function can never be both a template and virtual (the compiler would need to create an arbitrary large virtual function table). I am not exactly sure how you want to use your classes. I have used a combination of a template function in the interface that calls a virtual function that wraps the arbitrary type in a boost::any-object in a similar context but I'm not sure if thats applicable to your problem.

Comment: @MadScientist Yes, regarding the template and virtual method, which is why I was thinking to go for compile-time inheritance, with templates, but I'm not sure how would that work. Also, I would prefer to stick only to STL, without involving Boost, if there isn't a compelling reason to do so. Could you elaborate your design in more detail?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve with your design. Are the following assumptions correct? The user of CryptoProvider gets a pointer to a CryptoProvider-object and specifies the return type of the encrypt-Method. If the actual instance has a special version for the specified return type, the special version is used. If not, the generic implementation from the CryptoProvider-base-class ist used.

Comment: "but, if a derived class needs to do some extra processing on the data, it should be able to overwrite the base method" => So far I'm with you. Question is: If the client need to use the base class pointer/reference to call Encrypt() or not. If no, then the derived classes could provide an implementation with a different function name. If yes, I don't understand how you are going to get benefited by this. The clients will have to know the derived class specification in order to use the concrete CipherText.

Comment: @MadScientist As a valid use-case scenario, I would just create an `ElGamal crypto;` object, and I would use it to encrypt stuff like so: `crypto.Encrypt(plaintext)` (I oversimplified the example in the question). There are certain scenarios where I need to pass `crypto` around by reference, but I certainly don't need to use it as a pointer. At this point, I don't have any use scenario for run-time polymorphism, but, it could prove useful in the future...

Comment: @PermanentGuest At this point, run-time polymorphism is not a requirement, but I'm starting to think that I may need it later on. Anyway, at this point, I'm willing to just do without it. Different function names for each derived class for the Encrypt method seems like bad design to me. They should all be called Encrypt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See another way to achieve this. Slightly round-about, though...
This provides the possibility of a common implementation based on templates and derivability. Only problem is that the CipherText definition cannot be inside the derived classes. I guess this wouldn't be a big problem for you. If you can define these classes in a global scope, you could get away with the additional derivation.

```
template <typename T>
class CryptoProvider
{

public:
    virtual T Encrypt()
    {
        T data;

        return data;
    }
};

class PaillierBase
{
public:
   typedef int Ciphertext;
};

class Paillier : public PaillierBase, public CryptoProvider<PaillierBase::Ciphertext>
{
public:

};

class ElGamalBase
{
public:
    struct Ciphertext
    {
    public:
        int c1;
        int c2;
    };


};

class ElGamal : public ElGamalBase, public CryptoProvider<ElGamalBase::Ciphertext>
{
public:

};

class CustomEncryptorBase
{
public:
    struct Ciphertext
    {
    public:
        char* c1;
        int* c2;
    };


};

class CustomEncryptor : public CustomEncryptorBase, public CryptoProvider<CustomEncryptorBase::Ciphertext>
{
public:

    virtual CustomEncryptorBase::Ciphertext Encrypt()
    {
        CustomEncryptorBase::Ciphertext data;

        //  Do additional processing

        return data;
    }
};

int main()
{
    ElGamal e;
    ElGamalBase::Ciphertext c = e.Encrypt();

    CustomEncryptor ce;
    CustomEncryptorBase::Ciphertext c1 = ce.Encrypt();

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Yes, this is where I got with @n.m.'s suggestion and it will work, but it's quite unfortunate that I have to split the derived classes in two. I was hoping for some design that would help me avoid this. Maybe by decoupling the ciphertext types from the derived classes and just making them global, like `struct PaillierCiphertext`.

Comment: This is pretty much what I suggested below, only more verbose since you split things up more.

Answer (score 2):

All your child classes have the `Ciphertext` type defined to be different things. This suggest making it a template parameter of `CryptoProvider`.

```
template <typename T>
class CryptoProvider
{
public:
    virtual T Encrypt () { ... }
    typedef T Ciphertext;
};

class PaillierBase : public CryptoProvider<int> { ... }
```

IMHO CRTP is unnecessary here.

Comment: Well, that would be really neat, if it would work, but it seems that "error C2898: 'T CryptoProvider<T>::Encrypt(void)' : member function templates cannot be virtual" :( If there is any way to get around this limitation, most of my problems would be solved... Also, if the type is declared within `PaillierBase`, how can I then pass it to the `CryptoProvider` template?

Comment: I'm sorry that's sloppy editing on my part. Corrected by removing the `template` from function definition.

Comment: Well, you don't *have* to declare `Ciphertext` inside the `PaillierBase`. It is perfectly OK to declare it inside `CryptoProvider`, as I have done in the edited version. `PaillerBase` and other derived classes will only say what `Ciphertext` *is*.

Comment: Hm, this is getting really close to what I'm trying to achieve, but is it really possible to declare Ciphertext inside PaillierBase? This does not compile in VS2010: http://pastebin.com/mQQ5gQNN

Comment: No you cannot declare it inside (and CRTP won't help here either). I see two possible ways to solve this: (1) move the declaration out of the class (e.g. create a namespace for each cryptoprovider and put all related declarations there) or (2) just use e.g. `std::pair<int,int>` instead of a custom struct.

Comment: Yeap, it looks like moving the Ciphertext declaration out of the class is the only viable option. Although `std::pair` is usable, I would like to have a custom type name, which is much more scalable.

Comment: This approach doesn't scale very well: for each type you'll need yet another template parameter. With CRTP, you only need a single type of a class that declares all the types within itself.

Comment: @KubaOber: It's unclear what exactly CRTP buys in this case, since you need to declare all the types in a separate base class anyway. Could call it `PaillierTraits` instead of `PaillierBase` just as well, without inheriting it. So it's just like any other thing with too many parameters: if there are too many, group them into a compound entity.

Answer (score 1):

CRTP will work to provide compile-time overrideable functionality without need for virtual functions:

```
template <typename Derived> class CryptoProvider
{
public:
    typename Derived::Ciphertext Encrypt() {
        typename Derived::Ciphertext data;
        return data;
    }
};

class PaillierBase
{
public:
    typedef int Ciphertext;
};

class Paillier : public CryptoProvider<PaillierBase>
{
public:
    void test1() {
        Encrypt();
    }
};

class ElGamalBase
{
public:
    struct Ciphertext {
        int c1;
        int c2;
    };
};

class ElGamal : public CryptoProvider<ElGamalBase>
{
public:
    void test2() {
        Encrypt();
    }
};
```

The return types need to be declared in a base class that must be a complete type by the time the CRTP template gets instantiated when you derive from it. The code below doesn't work, at least in pre-C11 compilers: at point P, the class ElGamal is not a complete type yet, thus CryptoProvider::Encrypt() can't be instantiated. I don't know if C11 changes anything here. It's a silly shortcoming of the language, IMHO.

```
// Doesn't work, unfortunately
class ElGamal : public CryptoProvider<ElGamal> /* P */
{
public:
    struct Ciphertext {
        int c1;
        int c2;
    };
    void test2() {
        Encrypt();
    }
};
```

Comment: Indeed, quite unfortunate that C++ has this limitation. I would have hoped to avoid splitting each derived class in two, since it doesn't make much sense from a functional point of view.

Comment: The base class only needs to have the types defined, everything else goes into the final class. This is not a big drawback. The biggest win is still in not having to duplicate code. C++ is quite verbose, even more so than Java, it's a fact of life. It's a common misconception that C++ classes should follow product or even design functionally. They are language constructs. Look at any modern C++ template class library like [boost](http://www.boost.org) or [eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org). You'll see potentially hundreds of classes, only 10% of them perhaps forming a public API.

Comment: Since, on the long run, it might prove useful to benefit from runtime polymorphism, I think I will use the design that the others suggested. It's really good that I also have this alternative, though. Thank you!

Comment: You do realize that this is precisely what the accepted answer gives, except that there's no `virtual` keyword and that the accepted answer adds an extra unnecessary class? You're free to make the `Encrypt` method virtual if you wish.

Comment: Well, yes, OK. They are the almost the same, but I can't accept all 3 answers :) The thing is that I ended up decoupling the Ciphertext types from the classes, so I can use them in the template parameters. I have to modify quite a bit of code because of this, but I expect it to work, based on all the feedback I received here. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a base class called CipherText in which you hold the cipher text. Then, you can subclass that to the specific type that you need to return. You can specify the return type as a base class pointer.

Of course, this answer might be right or wrong based on what you are trying to do.